# How to use default values as well as Micronaut introspection validation with Kotlin Data class?

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I'm starting to learn Kotlin and Micronaut and am trying to build a basic CRUD app with a Rest API, but I'm having trouble with getting Bean validation to work with data classes. Right now I have:

*Task.kt*

```kotlin
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank

@Introspected
data class Task(
    val id: Int,
    @field:NotBlank val name: String,
    val description: String = "",
    val status: TaskStatus = TaskStatus.NOT_STARTED
)
```

*TaskController.kt*

```kotlin
@Controller("/task")
open class TaskController(private val taskRepository: TaskRepository) {

    @Post("/")
    open fun createTask(@Valid @Body task: Task): Task {
        return taskRepository.insert(task)
    }
}
```

*Test.kt*

```kotlin
@MicronautTest
class TaskListTest {

    @Inject
    @field:Client("/task")
    lateinit var client: RxHttpClient

    // Passes as expected
    @Test
    fun `basic insert`() {
        val request = HttpRequest.POST<Any>("/", object {
            val name = "foo"
            val description = "foo description"
            val status = TaskStatus.IN_PROGRESS
        })

        val response: Task = client.toBlocking().retrieve(request, Task::class.java)

        Assertions.assertEquals(response, Task(id=1, name="foo", description = "foo description", status = TaskStatus.IN_PROGRESS))
    }

    @Test
    fun `returns 400 if name is blank`() {
        val request = HttpRequest.POST<Any>("/", object {
            val name = ""
            val description = "foo description"
            val status = TaskStatus.IN_PROGRESS
        })

        Assertions.assertThrows(HttpClientResponseException::class.java) {
            client.toBlocking().retrieve(request, Task::class.java)
        }
    }

    // Fails but should pass
    @Test
    fun `adds default values if optional fields are not provided`() {
        val request = HttpRequest.POST<Any>("/", object {
            val name = "foo"
        })

        val response: Task = client.toBlocking().retrieve(request, Task::class.java)

        Assertions.assertEquals(response, Task(id=1, name="foo", status = TaskStatus.NOT_STARTED))
    }

}
```

I'm not sure why it is returning a 400 if the `description` or `status` fields are not provided. It should just use the defaults defined in the data class, right? And since there are no other validations specified on those fields, it should just work.

Any ideas what I am missing?